# Архитектура Telegram бота с тремя процессами

Tags: python, многопоточность, sqlite, telegram-bot, flask

Есть большой Telegram бот. На данный момент он разделен на 3 программы.

1. Основной бот, написан на `PyTelegramBotApi`, запускается так:

   ```
   while True:
       try:
           bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=2)
           break
       except Exception as ex:
           print(ex)
           bot.stop_polling()
           time.sleep(15)
   ```
2. По ТЗ нужен второй бот, который фактически является панелью управления для первого, через него делаются рассылки пользователям, а так же изменение информации в базе данных. Запускается аналогично.
3. Третья программа – это обработчик уведомлений об оплате, которые приходят на сервер. Он написан на `flask` и запускается так:

   ```
   app.threading = True
   app.run(host=host_ip, debug=True)
   ```

Все 3 программы я запускаю в трех разных скринах (используя `screen` из Linux). То есть фактически он работает в трех разных процессах. Каждая из программ читает и изменяет содержимое одной БД на SQLite. Несколько раз у меня возникала ошибка `Database is locked`, но я кажется решил её, уменьшив `timeout` – `conn = sqlite3.connect(config.database, check_same_thread=False, timeout=1)`

Проблема в том, что, не смотря на то, что все работает, мне кажется, что данное решение будет плохо работать на продакшне. Главная проблема, которую я вижу – при обращении одного из процессов к БД, остальные 2 не блокируются, то есть ошибка `Database is locked` еще может возникнуть. Кроме того такой способ запуска просто неудобен (надо создать 3 скрина и запустить в каждом нужную программу.)

Подскажите как можно решить эти проблемы и есть ли еще какие-то.

Comment: у вас тут несколько вопросов, которые могли бы быть полезны *изолировано* (как отдельные вопросы) возможно *бОльшему* числу людей: к примеру, решение проблемы *"способ запуска просто неудобен (надо создать 3 скрина и запустить в каждом нужную программу.)"* может быть полезно и людям, которые не пишут telegram боты (возможные ответы: systemd/supervisord сервисы, docker-compose up, etc). Ответ на вопрос «что делать c *"Database is locked"* при обращении из нескольких процессов» может быть полезен даже если в вашем конкретном случае ответом может быть "используйте postgres или другую DB"

Comment: по архитектуре: если ещё не много кода написано и в основном вводом/выводом занимаетесь, то можно всё в одном процессе с помощью async.io выразить (note: использование одного процесса не означает, что можно забыть о необходимости модулиризации вашего кода)

Comment: почему выбрали именно sqlite? если поставите, допустим postgres, у вас не будет проблем с одновременной записью в бд.

Comment: таймаут нужно увеличивать. sqlite, даже в режиме wal, не умеет в многопоток в транзакции.

Answer (score 2):

Читаем про sqlite:

> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time. Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in time, however.

Т.е. читать из базы одновременно несколькими процессами можно, писать - только одним.

Из этого следует:

1. замените sqlite, например на postgres или nosql-решения. тогда локов не будет. иначе делайте цикл и ждите пока lock не пройдет (но для продакшн - это так себе решение).
2. процессы можно запускать фоновом режиме, тогда не нужно иметь три screen'а. либо завернуть в supervisord, либо использовать контейнеры в docker.